# No feedback from test AT command sent by esp32 to cellular/gnss module

Tags: c++, arduino, uart, at-command

Hello I am trying to send a test AT command to make sure my esp32 to cellular module connection is working correctly.  The cellular module is a Quectel BG95 and the ESP32 is a ESP-WROOM-32UE ([datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/891/esp32_wroom_32e_esp32_wroom_32ue_datasheet_en-1855879.pdf))  The commands will be in a format like the image below, taken from the modem's manual.

[image: note]
[image: manual excerpt]

The C++ code is being uploaded through Arduino IDE. And then the ESP uses its RXD and TXD pins GPIO 16 and 17 respectively to make a UART connection.  Here is the code:

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
int greenpower = 32;
int led = 33;


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial2.begin(115200,SERIAL_8N1,16,17);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); //for verifying power to the board
  pinMode(greenpower, OUTPUT); //for allowing power to auxillary processes
  digitalWrite(greenpower, HIGH); //allow power to aux devices
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);  //apply power to verification circuit
  delay(1000);

}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Started");
  Serial2.write("AT\r");
  while (!Serial2.available()) continue;
  while (Serial2.available()) {
    int g = Serial2.read();
    Serial.write(g);
    Serial.println(g);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

**The code has been edited to address some of the concerns in the comments/answers.**  That is adding a delay after the test AT command: `Serial2.write("AT\r");` and added the carriage return character at the end. When I upload this program and check the serial monitor I see "Started" but just get a 0 from the `Serial.println(g);`.  Each execution cycle takes a whopping 15s.

It was suggested that I replace: `Serial2.write("AT\r");`with either
`Serial2.println("AT\r")` or `Serial2.write("AT\r\n");` as a new line is needed for modem to recognize AT command.  The first replacement yielded no result but the second yielded a response, which is below.  But appears to be just an MCU error, nothing to do with a connection to the modem.

```
19:48:21.715 -> Started
19:48:36.692 -> Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
19:48:36.692 -> Memory dump at 0x400d1c6c: b41f6520 92f01a64 a0a20022
19:48:36.692 -> Core 1 register dump:
19:48:36.692 -> PC      : 0x400d1c70  PS      : 0x00060530  A0      : 0x800d0db4  A1      : 0x3ffb1f50  
19:48:36.692 -> A2      : 0x3ffbdc5c  A3      : 0x00000000  A4      : 0x3f40012c  A5      : 0x00000010  
19:48:36.692 -> A6      : 0xffffffff  A7      : 0x00000008  A8      : 0x800d1c70  A9      : 0x3ffb1f10  
19:48:36.692 -> A10     : 0x00000001  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x3ffb8218  A13     : 0x00000000  
19:48:36.744 -> A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0xff000000  SAR     : 0x00000018  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000000  
19:48:36.744 -> EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4000c28c  LEND    : 0x4000c296  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  
19:48:36.744 -> 
19:48:36.744 -> ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000
19:48:36.744 -> 
19:48:36.744 -> Backtrace: 0x400d1c70:0x3ffb1f50 0x400d0db1:0x3ffb1f70 0x400d0c94:0x3ffb1f90 0x400d1499:0x3ffb1fb0 0x40086155:0x3ffb1fd0
19:48:36.744 -> 
19:48:36.744 -> Rebooting...
19:48:36.744 -> ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
19:48:36.744 -> 
19:48:36.744 -> rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x36 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
19:48:36.744 -> configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
19:48:36.744 -> clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
19:48:36.744 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
19:48:36.791 -> load:0x3fff0018,len:4
19:48:36.791 -> load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
19:48:36.791 -> load:0x40078000,len:10124
19:48:36.791 -> load:0x40080400,len:5856
19:48:36.791 -> entry 0x400806a8
19:48:37.869 -> Started
```

**Verifying Hardware**
It was asked if I have verified the RXD and TXD connections among other hardware items.  I have verified the UART connections but to make things more difficult the esp's UART pins go through a logic level shifter to take things from 3.3V to 1.8V.

[image: Schematic]
[Datasheet for logic level shifter](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0108e.pdf)

So I soldered 4 wires to the PCB.  2 wires to the ESP's pads for RXD and TXD and 2 wires on the 1.8V side of the level shifter headed to the modem's TXD and RXD.  The first two images show readings from the scope on the ESP's TXD pad (yellow vary 0-2.7V) superimposed with a readings after the level shifter (purple vary 0-1.8V).  The third picture shows the readings on the ESP/MCU's RXD line which are totally flat.  On the MCU side of the level shifter it is 3.3V and on the Modem side it is 1.8V.  Because the level shifter works on the ESP's TXD line, I presume it works on the ESP's RXD line.

[image: scope pic1]
[image: scope pic2]
[image: scope pic3]

To get these readings I used the code below (different from the code above) because with my loops executing only every 15s I couldn't get readings so I changed write frequency to 10ms.

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
int greenpower = 32;
int led = 33;


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial2.begin(115200,SERIAL_8N1,16,17);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); //for verifying power to the board
  pinMode(greenpower, OUTPUT); //for allowing power to auxillary processes
  digitalWrite(greenpower, HIGH); //allow power to aux devices
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);  //apply power to verification circuit
  delay(1000);

}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Started");
  Serial2.write(1);
  delay(10);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're literally sending `AT+<cmd>=?`, where `<cmd>` was supposed to stand in for a specific command. Replace that with what you want to read, and as mentioned above, send a Carriage Return after.

Comment: I found a datasheet for the modem: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1949966/Quectel-Bg95-Series.html?page=47#manual and it mentions a debug serial port. Its capabilities & use are not described, but I would want to connect its 2 pins to the 2 spare lines of that level shifter, and then use a USB-to-TTL_serial adapter and PC to check the BG95.  *"I do own an oscilloscope ..."* -- Good.  Verify the ESP32's TxD is good on one 'scope channel, and appears on the other side of the xlater at BG95's RxD using another 'scope channel.  Then look for output on BG95's TxD as a response.

Comment: I wish I could go back and include this debug UART in my pcb design.  I think I will on the next revision though... I imagine there are many uses to this!  I do own an arbitrary wave generator so I should be able to hook one of the spare pins to this and then measure with the oscilloscope on the other end.  But I have tried @danz code and I am now reading something I am not sure if it is write though will add details.

Comment: *"the second yielded a response, ... Is this feedback from the modem?"* -- That is a system failure, a kernel panic, caused by the attempted execution of an illegal instruction (bad jump into uninitialized memory?).  If your code still has the double output of `Serial.write(g);` and `Serial.println(g);`, then those messages could not possibly be from the modem.

Comment: What type of IC is the BG95?  Are you sure the board is laid out properly?  This problem is veering away from a programming problem that is suitable for this site.  What use is a *"arbitrary wave generator"* for this problem?  You can probably find a youtube video on how to measure TTL serial with a scope.

Comment: @sawdust I see, I am a little disappointed that the error messages were from the MCU.  As I mentioned above I don't have the debug serial port.  But I will attempt to scope the TXD on both sides of the level shifter.  I am not sure what to look for so I will watch a video.  But I imagine I will tell the MCU to write to the TXD and look for this signal before/after the level shifter.

Comment: @sawdust the code doesn't mention the RTS or CTS connection.  In the hardware integration manual it specifically states that "1.8 V power domain.
If unused, keep this pin open." for both RTS and CTS should this be added to the code?

Comment: RTS and CTS are for hardware flow-control.  Read the BG95 manual.  It states that *"hardware flow control is disabled by default."*  Hence, diddling the ESP32's RTS or sensing the CTS should have no effect.  All you're doing is speculating on inconsequential matters instead of first resolving fundamental issues like inspecting the TxD and RxD signals with a 'scope.

Comment: @sawdust there was no need to add the second half of your comment above.  I plan to do as advised as soon as I get a moment.  But I read this statement in the manual and was asking for clarification because I didn’t know the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're forgetting to terminate each AT command line with a carriage return character, hence no response.

---

**Addendum**

[I think I've already pointed out the obvious flaw in your code, but now it seems that your situation could/may have a plethora of issues.]

Have you verified that the modem is properly connected to the Arduino, i.e. there is a ***ground*** connection as well as each **RxD** and **TxD** are connected to complementary pins?
Have you verified that the modem is properly powered up and functional?
Can you probe those **RxD** and **TxD** lines with an oscilloscope?

The modem may not respond instantaneously after receiving the AT command, yet your code does expect that.
A (fixed) delay could be inserted between the `Serial2.write("AT\r")` and `while (Serial2.available()) {...}` statements.
Alternatively I've seen a `while (!Serial2.available()) continue;` employed to *wait* for a response to become available (instead of using an arbitrary hardcoded delay).

---

**Addendum 2**

The addition of 'scope photos clearly indicate that you have a problem in the hardware domain.

> The third picture shows the readings on the ESP/MCU's RXD line which are totally flat.

No, that's not a *"totally flat"* trace, but a noisy signal with  spikes.
Why is that?
And of course there's no response/data because you're sending a garbage value <s>at the improper baudrate</s>, instead of an AT command <s>at the expected baudrate</s>.

Comment: Looks like I did forget to attach <CR> I changed my command to AT+<cmd>=?<CR> and am getting 0.  Went ahead and tried another test command AT+QCFGEXT=?<CR> and am getting the same 0 response

Comment: `<CR>` would be BNF ([Backus Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)) notation, which is notation to describe/define a programming/command language syntax.  The string notation would be "\r" for a carriage return.  Use the string "AT\r" for the *simplest* modem command to evoke a (known) response.

Comment: I see I have made this change.  Still seeing the 0 but I notice that I am printing the variable "g" which is an integer.... This I imagine should be string?

Comment: *"This I imagine should be string?"* -- It could, but it's all just numbers (or encoded symbols) to a computer, and depends on how you want to handle the data . A byte (stored in an int) value of zero would correspond to the ASCII character NUL, which is a non-printable control character. So the `Serial.write(g);` statement would display nothing for the NUL character. The `Serial.println(g);` statement would then display the int value in default decimal representation, which is "0", with line termination.

Comment: Edited the question to address some of the concerns outlined in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

By your description, it seems that the modem is not getting your AT command.
Normally, the BG95 needs also the new line character to receive the AT command. So you either use `Serial2.println("AT\r")` or `Serial2.write("AT\r\n")`.

Make sure your ESP32 TX and RX point to the Modem's RX and TX respectively.

Comment: Interestingly I tried the Serial2.println("AT\r") and no luck.  But I tried Serial2.write("AT\r\n") and got a bunch of feedback from this!  Adding in the description as I am not sure what this means, whether I have connection or not that is.

Comment: The BG95 AT Commands manual clearly states that a carriage return character terminates an AT command.  Your claim that a line feed is also needed has no basis in fact (for this modem).

Comment: I'm glad it worked. 
A line feed is necessary if your UART is not using hardware control. It's the best way for the modem to know that you are finishing your AT command.

Comment: Your problem now is that you are getting a string back and you're trying to store in a int. Use `String rsp;` `rsp = Serial2.readString();`

Comment: I went ahead and gave it a shot.  I just replaced int g = Serial2.read(); Serial.write(g); Serial.println(g); with the following lines: String rsp; rsp = Serial2.readString(); Serial.println(rsp);  This may not be what you were suggesting exactly.  If so let me know, but I am still getting the same "Panic Error"