# Python Serial Read

Tags: python, pyserial, uart, modem

Having trouble reading serial data from a USB modem and can't find anyone with the same issue.

Using the code below, I can write to the serial port successfully but when I read, the terminal just sits there accepting input but does nothing with it. I can type anything I like and enter carriage returns but they don't do anything. It's like I've created an infinite input loop but I don't see how that could have happened.
Eventually I have to Crtl-c out of the program.

I've tried other approaches, such as reading a specified number of bytes or reading into a variable and looping through it but critically, a call to inWaiting() or in_waiting returns 0, so there's clearly nothing to read despite the write command being successfully accepted by the modem.

Anyone got any thoughts on where this infinite loop is coming from and why I'm not seeing my modem's responses?

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB2", 115200)

time.sleep(1)
ser.write(b'\r\n' + b'at' + b'\r\n')

time.sleep(1)
print(ser.readline())
```

**SOLVED:**
I think timeout made the difference (thanks to RaulG). I started seeing either b'\r\n' or in another case b'at\r\n' being returned and found that my response was being split over multiple lines and seems to include an echo.

With the following code I was able to see the full response.

Code:

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port="/dev/ttyUSB2", baudrate=115200, timeout=5)

time.sleep(0.5)
ser.write(b'at\r\n')

time.sleep(0.5)
print(ser.readline())
print(ser.readline())
print(ser.readline())
```

Output:

```
b'at\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'OK\r\n'
```

Comment: (1) First verify that the modem and connection are operational using proven software.  E.G. use a terminal emulation program, such as **minicom**, rather than your untested code.  Unless you want to waste a week or more wondering what could be wrong, such as this guy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68607115/no-feedback-from-test-at-command-sent-by-esp32-to-cellular-gnss-module/68608675#68608675  (2)  The simplest AT command is simply "AT\r', which should get a "\r\nOK\r\n" response.

Comment: Already verified the connection using 'screen', this is why I said that I can write successfully. I have used my code to write over the serial connection and then verified it's success using a standard terminal emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the `ser.readline()` command is the infinite loop. It waits until there is a `\n` Charakter in the input buffer. You can avoid the loop by specifying a timeout in the initialization of the `serial.Serial` Object like this (timeout in seconds)

```py
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB2',115200,timeout=2)
```

Now to the part that there is nothing that you receive from the modem. This might have different reasons and cannot be properly answered by the informations you have provided.
First there might be something wrong with your usb to serial adapter. Then you might have incorrectly wired something or your modem might have a problem electrically or with its software.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the infinite loop. I'll try this out when I get a chance.

Regarding the connection, the modem exposes a mPCIe interface that I'm interacting with via an adapter that exposes a USB-C interface.
I have no issues communicating with and operating the modem using this hardware over standard terminal emulators (PuTTY, TeraTerm, Minicom, screen, PComm, etc.) only when I try to read serial responses using Python.

In my experience, the hardware and firmware are both fully functional, so I believe this is still a Python question.

Comment: You might have to specify the correct form of bytes you are receiving back from the modem. See [this](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#classes) page of the doc. There might be an issue regarding parity or bitsize or stop-bits

Comment: The timeout is excellent but as you've noticed, it doesn't solve the core problem since the timeout wouldn't be necessary if I was actually receiving responses.

I have tried specifying 8N1 with hardware and software flow control set to False, which is what I normally use on terminal emulators but unfortunately it has not made a difference.